# Configure S3 bucket to allow getObject only on some directory for anonymous

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-permissions

I try to do some particulars configuration for the permission of Amazon S3 but it doesn't work.

I use a bucket Amazon S3 to store files for a website. Some files are public, so everybody can see them. But a part of these files should be private and are stored in specific directories. These private files should be present to users of the website depending of some conditions (if they have buy the image). In that case, the website will send the file to the user.

Presently, it seems all files are accessible for everybody despite the fact the bucket isn't public. In the Access Control List, I only give right for the user who is used by the website to communicate with the API.

But files stay visible and downloadable by anonymous users if you have the direct URL. I find that weird but like it's not a problem for public files, I thought it was normal and I change Bucket Policy for the private directory like this:

```
{
        "Sid": "Stmt1538509082866",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/private/*"
        ]
 }
```

But this rule deny the right to see and download files for my specific user. I try to put the allow just behind for him, but it doesn't work in that way. I thought I could use a condition, but, not apparently for a specific user.

I precise I work on this project since recently and I didn't initialize the bucket, so, maybe it has a misconfiguration I did see.

Thank you.

Comment: The first thing you'll want to do is understand why this isn't already working as expected -- everything in S3 is always private by default, so there must be *something* making content public.  Check the individual object permissions.  If they were set to public, it's in your best interests to fix this rather than try to patch it with a policy statement that should be unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this response. I verified and indeed, my files have all the READ permission for anonymous individually....... Now, I need to find how to fix that easily without change permissions of every file manually.

Comment: The files will have to be fixed individually, but not necessarily manually... it should be possible to script this using aws-cli.